# Types of custom input component's Props with React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hook-form, typing

I'm trying to create a generic custom FormInput component with React Hook Form but I'm struggling with the types

I would call my component like this ...

```
<FormInput control={control} name={"name"}></FormInput>
```

... and keep autocompletion on name property.

My FormInput looks like

```
type Props = {
  control: any
  name: any
  rules?: any
  shouldUnregister?: boolean
  style?: StyleProp<TextStyle>
  secureTextEntry?: boolean
  placeholder?: string
}

const FormInput = ({
  name,
  control,
  rules,
  style,
  secureTextEntry,
  placeholder,
}: Props) => {
  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      rules={rules}
      render={({
        field: { onChange, onBlur, value },
        fieldState: { error },
      }) => (
        <>
          <Input
            onBlur={onBlur}
            onChangeText={onChange}
            value={value}
            style={style}
            secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
            placeholder={placeholder}
          />
          {error && <Text>{error.message || "Error"}</Text>}
        </>
      )}
    ></Controller>
  )
}

export default FormInput
```

and I don't know what types {control, name, rules} should be.

I've tried this

```
type Props<T> = {
  control: Control<T, any>
  name: Path<T>
  rules?: {For this I have no Idea}
  [...]
}

const FormInput = <T,>({
  [...]
}: Props<T>) => {
  [...]

//Call with 
<FormInput<Program> control={control} name={"name"}></FormInput>
```

I have this error on {control}:

> Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'FieldValues'.
> This type parameter might need an `extends FieldValues` constraint.

But even with extends it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1):

your component props should be like this

```
interface FormInputProps<
  TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues,
  TName extends Path<TFieldValues> = Path<TFieldValues>,
> extends ControllerProps<TFieldValues, TName> {}
```

and your component should be like this

```
 const FormInput = <
  TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues,
  TName extends Path<TFieldValues> = Path<TFieldValues>,
>({
  name,
  rules,
  render,
  ...rest
}: InputControllerProps<TFieldValues, TName>) => { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I've done what you did and I have no type error but now when i call my component it require render method like the Controller component or it should be generic. Maybe I did a mistake ?

Comment: the render prop has to be required since the controller doesn't know anything about the component you want to render.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from Mohammad's answer, not needing the `render` prop:

```
interface TextInputProps<
  TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues,
  TName extends Path<TFieldValues> = Path<TFieldValues>
> extends UseControllerProps<TFieldValues, TName> {
  disabled?: boolean;
  label: string;
  placeholder?: string;
}

const TextInput = <
  TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues,
  TName extends Path<TFieldValues> = Path<TFieldValues>
>({
  control,
  defaultValue,
  disabled = false,
  label,
  name,
  placeholder = "",
  rules,
}: TextInputProps<TFieldValues, TName>) => {
  return (
    <Controller
      control={control}
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      name={name}
      rules={rules}
      render={({ field: { onChange, ref, value }, fieldState: { error } }) => {
        // ...
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default TextInput;
```